# Netbeans type info for Scala

Tags: scala, netbeans, types

In the IntelliJ Scala plugin, there is a "Type Info" command that when run with the mouse hovering over a variable, shows the variable's (inferred) type.

Is there something similar in the Netbeans Scala plugin?

Comment: +1 because you used Netbeans :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetBeans has this too. See screenshot here [type inference in NetBeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf4RK.jpg)

You need to press `Ctrl` key and then hover the mouse.

This works in NetBeans 6.8 with Scala 6.8. I haven't mixed other versions.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. "Command" key in OsX.

Answer (score 1):

Hold down Ctrl while floating.